# Making sense of git diff

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a file "file.txt" in my repo which contains three lines:

```
1
2
3
```

This file has been committed. However, if I now add a fourth line to the file, it looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

When I enter "git diff file.txt" it gives me the following output:

```
diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt
index 5f5fbe7..b178657 100644
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 1
 2
-3
\ No newline at end of file
+3
+4
\ No newline at end of file
```

In other words, at row 1 three lines have been removed and 4 have been added according to git diff (`@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@`). This doesn't make sense to me, as all I did was to add a fourth line - so I would expect the output (`-0,0 +4,1`)

What is happening here?

---

I am running git on Windows 7.

Comment: That is the expected behavior of `diff` for files not ending in newline, see e.g. https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff/issues/94 .

Answer (score 1):

> at row 1 three lines have been removed

No, rows 1 and 2 have not been changed. Diff shows some context, a few lines before and after the change, to make it easier to understand.

The diff is showing line 3 removed and lines 3 and 4 added. Line 3 changed because it didn't have an end of line before but does after (hence diff showing " at row 1 three lines have been removed").

Answer (score 0):

You've changed line 3 and added line 4.

The change in line 3 was the new line.

`git diff --unified=0` may make more sense (this shows only changed lines).

`diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
index 5f5fbe7..b178657 100644
--- a/a.txt
+++ b/a.txt
@@ -3 +3,2 @@
-3
\ No newline at end of file
+3
+4
\ No newline at end of file`

It's best seen in color:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UNIX defines a line as "string of characters ending in a line terminator". Thus, almost all UNIX-based editors will have lines like this:

```
1\n
2\n
3\n
```

where `\n` represents the LF character, signifying the end of a line. If you would add a fourth line here, it would indeed be just one new line.

Windows does not share this definition, and many Windows-based editors consider the CR+LF combination (noted below as `\r\n`) as line *separator*, not line *terminator*. As `git` noted with "\ No newline at end of file", your file was

```
1\r\n
2\r\n
3
```

When you added another line, you got

```
1\r\n
2\r\n
3\r\n
4
```

So from `git`'s UNIX-centric point of view, you did modify line #3, by appending `\r\n` to it.

Now to the misunderstanding about `diff` output format: by default, `diff` is giving you the "unified" format, with some context around the changes. The changes are just the lines that have `+` or `-` prefixed to them: the original line 3 has been removed, and new lines 3 and 4 are inserted. The notation `@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@` says that the snippet below describes lines 1-3 of the old file, and lines 1-4 of the new file. Normally, unified diff output defaults to also give you two lines of context before and after each change, to aid humans in understanding exactly what is changed (`-U2`). If you don't want the context, you can switch it off with `-U0`.